# GitHub repository disabled when changing from private to public

Tags: github

I changed a GitHub repo from private to public and it gives me this error when trying to push changes from the terminal:

```
ERROR: Repository `user/repo-name' is disabled.
Please ask the owner to check their account.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I can still view the code and make commits but it won’t push the changes. I also am not able to fork the repo - it says that “Cannot fork because repository is locked”. I already have my SSH key working on GitHub, which was the only answer I’ve found when researching this. Everything worked fine before I changed the repo from private to public. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you contacted GitHub support?

Comment: yes, no response yet.

Comment: Some users mention that only their support can unlock the repository, so I’d recommend waiting

Comment: Hm, github had an outage earlier today, maybe you did something during the outage and that locker your account? Not sure, just guessing.

Comment: Yeah, maybe it had something to do with that. However, they've contacted me back and got it fixed thankfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacted GitHub support and they unlocked the repository. It may have happened because I changed the repo from private to public during their outage. Everything works fine now